# Deploying Hibernate Web Application on Tomcat running on Debian

Tags: java, linux, spring, hibernate, tomcat

With reference to my [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826227/deploying-hibernate-application-with-tomcat-on-raspberry-pi), I am having some issues when running a enterprise-scale web application on Linux. Before investing into a real staging machine, I thought that I should give it a try on Raspbery Pi, but now, we're running the application on a **real** Debian computer.

The issue is as same as my previous question.

> At first, I thought that it is more of a tomcat issue, but now, I am
> thinking that it is a <strike>Raspberry Pi</strike> **Linux** issue.
>
> This exact same configuration works on our windows servers, but I cant
> figure out why it does not work on the <strike>Pi</strike> **Staging Macine**!

## The problem(s):

The tomcat is not registering the JNDI names which I have defined in the application context and Hibernate is not able to connect to the database even though correct database URL is supplied.

### In my $CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/$appname.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" cookies="true">
    <Resource name="stagingDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/preview"
                username="root" password="root" />
</Context>
```

I have defined a Spring bean as;

```
    <bean id="velocityConfig"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">

        <property name="velocityProperties">

            <map>

                <entry key="resource.loader" value="ds" />
                <entry key="ds.resource.loader.class"
                    value="com.simplestack.velocity.config.SimpleStackDataSourceResourceLoader" />
                <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.table" value="Catalog" />
                <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.keycolumn" value="name" />
                <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.templatecolumn" value="html" />
                <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.defaultVendorId"
                    value="1" />
                <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.defaultSiteId" value="20160109144" />
                <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.datasource" value="java:comp/env/stagingDS" />
                <entry key="ds.resource.loader.resource.timestampcolumn"
                    value="lastmod" />

            </map>

        </property>
    </bean>
```

It gives me `NamingConventionException` saying that `stagingDS` is not defined.

#### This might be a Tomcat issue as well, so I am posting the output of version.sh as well.

[image: Screenshot of PuTTY]

#### Hibernate;

I am calling this method to create a session factory

```
protected static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(File cfgfile, File[] hbmfiles, String dburl, String dbuser, String dbpassword, String dbdriver, String treecacheConfigFile) 
            throws Exception{
        logger.info("Hibernate Configuration File Path:"+cfgfile.getPath());
        for (int i=0; i<hbmfiles.length; i++)
            logger.info("Hibernate Mapping File Path:"+hbmfiles[i].getPath());
        logger.info("Hibernate Using JDBC, dburl:"+dburl+" dbuser:"+dbuser+" dbdriver:"+dbdriver);

        Configuration hibernateConfig = new Configuration();
        for (int i=0; i<hbmfiles.length; i++)
            hibernateConfig = addHbmFile(hibernateConfig, hbmfiles[i]);

//      TODO: Add the audit interceptors
//      AuditInterceptor auditInterceptor = new AuditInterceptor();
//      addDefaultInterceptor(hibernateConfig, auditInterceptor);
//      addEventListeners(hibernateConfig);
        
        hibernateConfig.configure(cfgfile);
        logger.info("Configfile:"+cfgfile);
        
        if (treecacheConfigFile != null){
            hibernateConfig.setProperty("hibernate.cache.configuration_file", treecacheConfigFile);
            logger.info("hibernate.cache.configuration_file:"+treecacheConfigFile);
        }
        
        hibernateConfig.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", dburl);
        hibernateConfig.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", dbuser);
        hibernateConfig.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", dbpassword);
        hibernateConfig.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", dbdriver);
        
        
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = hibernateConfig.buildSessionFactory();
        //TODO:set a separate session factory
//      auditInterceptor.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        
        return sessionFactory;

    }
```

The session factory creation is successful, but in my log file, I see these:-

```
2016-06-15 08:04:54,504 INFO  [com.simplestack.SessionFactoryPool] Building Hibernate STAGING Session Factory...
2016-06-15 08:04:54,504 INFO  [com.simplestack.SessionFactoryPool] Hibernate Configuration File Path:/SimpleStack/tomcat/webapps/staging/WEB-INF/hibernatecfg/hibernate_mysql.cfg.xml
2016-06-15 08:04:54,505 INFO  [com.simplestack.SessionFactoryPool] Hibernate Mapping File Path:/SimpleStack/tomcat/webapps/staging/WEB-INF/hibernate
2016-06-15 08:04:54,505 INFO  [com.simplestack.SessionFactoryPool] Hibernate Using JDBC, dburl:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/preview dbuser:root dbdriver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2016-06-15 08:04:55,173 WARN  [org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver] HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
2016-06-15 08:04:55,284 WARN  [org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver] HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
2016-06-15 08:04:55,327 WARN  [org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver] HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
2016-06-15 08:04:55,380 WARN  [org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver] HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
2016-06-15 08:04:55,408 WARN  [org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver] HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
2016-06-15 08:04:55,434 WARN  [org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver] HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
2016-06-15 08:04:55,459 WARN  [org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver] HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
2016-06-15 08:04:55,483 WARN  [org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver] HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
2016-06-15 08:04:55,505 WARN  [org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver] HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
2016-06-15 08:04:55,514 INFO  [com.simplestack.SessionFactoryPool] Configfile:/SimpleStack/tomcat/webapps/staging/WEB-INF/hibernatecfg/hibernate_mysql.cfg.xml
2016-06-15 08:04:55,882 WARN  [org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass] HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): com.simplestack.hibernate.domainmodel.Siteproperty
2016-06-15 08:04:55,883 WARN  [org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass] HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): com.simplestack.hibernate.domainmodel.Siteproperty
2016-06-15 08:04:55,928 WARN  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] HHH000022: c3p0 properties were encountered, but the org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider provider class was not found on the classpath; these properties are going to be ignored.
2016-06-15 08:04:56,466 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl] HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

**I have tried putting the JNDI name in**

1. $CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/$appname.xml
2. $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/$appname/META-INF/context.xml
3. $CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml
4. $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml

But the problem still resides.

We are still very confused by what it is... Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a Database Connection Issue.

```
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Usually means that your Database server is down or is in an IP/Hostname other than localhost.